# How to mark functions as `@deprecate`d?

Tags: julia, deprecated

**(Question refers to Julia version v1.5)**

I'm trying to understand how the `@deprecate` macro works in Julia. The [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@deprecate) is unfortunately not clear to me:

> `@deprecate old new [ex=true]`
>
> Deprecate method old and specify the replacement call new. Prevent
> @deprecate from exporting old by setting ex to false. @deprecate
> defines a new method with the same signature as old.
>
> Warning:
> As of Julia 1.5, functions defined by @deprecate do not print warning when julia is run without the --depwarn=yes flag set, as the default value of --depwarn option is no. The warnings are printed from tests run by Pkg.test().
>
> Examples
>
> `julia> @deprecate old(x) new(x)`
>
> old (generic function with 1 method)
>
> `julia> @deprecate old(x) new(x)`
>
> false old (generic function with 1 method)

So what do I do?

```
function old(x::Int)
    print("Old behavior")
end

function new(x::Int)
    print("New behavior")
end

# Adding true/false argument doesn't change my observations.
@deprecate old(x) new(x)  # false 


old(3)
# Prints "Old behaviour". No warning. 
# Also: The deprecation is not mentioned in the help (julia>? old)
```

The aim of this `@deprecate` macro seems to be replacing functions? I find that counterintuitive. How can mark a function as deprecated (i.e. users should receive a warning and a hint what to use as a replacement, also it should be in the documentation)?

edit: I noticed my error. The signatures (in my case the `::Int`) have to be identical for this to work. However, how do I get a warning?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Imagine you have this method as part of the public API of your library in version 1:

```
# v1.0.0
mult3(x::Int) = 3x
```

In version 2, you'd like to stop supporting `mult3` (which is a breaking change). But the same feature will still be available using a more general method:

```
# v2.0.0
mult(x, y) = x * y
```

Users of version 1 are used to using `mult3`, which means that their code will break when they will update to v2. Therefore, you might want to release an intermediate version in the v1.x family, where `mult3` exists but is deprecated and implemented in terms of `mult`:

```
# v1.1 - transition

# This is the new API for v2
mult(x, y) = x*y

# The old API is still supported, but deprecated and implemented using the old one
@deprecate mult3(x::Int) mult(3, x)

# The above is more or less equivalent to defining
# function mult3(x::Int)
#    # print an error message is `--depwarn` has been set
#    return mult(3, x)
# end
```

The v1 API is not broken in late v1.x versions, but users calling deprecated methods will see the following kind of messages to help them transition to the newer v2 API:

```
julia> mult3(14)
┌ Warning: `mult3(x::Int)` is deprecated, use `mult(3, x)` instead.
│   caller = top-level scope at REPL[3]:1
└ @ Core REPL[3]:1
42
```

(but starting with Julia 1.5, the warning will only be shown if `--depwarn=yes` has been provided in Julia's command line or if it appears in a test suite run by `Pkg.test()`)

---

Alternatively, and as mentioned in comments, you may want to leave the old implementation around, simply warning users when they call it. To this end, you can use `Base.depwarn` directly:

```
# v1.1 - transition

# This is the new API for v2
mult(x, y) = x*y

# The old API is still supported, but deprecated
# It is implemented by itself:
function mult3(x)
    Base.depwarn("`mult3(x)` is deprecated, use `mult(3,x)` instead.", :mult3)
    return 3x
end
```

When `--depwarn=yes` has been provided in Julia's command line, this produces the same kind of warning as `@deprecate`:

```
julia> mult3(14)
┌ Warning: `mult3(x)` is deprecated, use `mult(3,x)` instead.
│   caller = top-level scope at REPL[4]:1
└ @ Core REPL[4]:1
42
```

Starting with Julia 1.6, `depwarn` will accept a keyword argument to force warning emission even when users haven't asked for them with `--depwarn=yes`:

```
julia> Base.depwarn("Foo is deprecated", :foo, force=true)
┌ Warning: Foo is deprecated
│   caller = ip:0x0
└ @ Core :-1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This explains the thinking behind what `@deprecate` does. I assme the warnings were disabled by default when everyone started complaining about all functions being renamed every version. On the other hand, *how do I achieve what I want? (Do NOT replace the method, perhaps even allow not to specify a replacement, always show the warning and include in help text)*. Is the answer that such functionality does not exist in the standard library?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. "always show the warning" -> if you mean to disregard `--depwarn`, then I guess `@deprecate` is not what you want, and I'm not sure you'll find any alternative that would not follow the meaning of this particular command-line option. As for the help text, I guess it could be argued that `@deprecate` could accept docstrings so that deprecated functions can be documented. You could maybe file an issue about this. Or use `@doc` to manually document deprecated functions if you want.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka, I think what you're asking is, how do you leave the old implementation around? You can also leave it in place and use `Base.depwarn` inside the method body to direct users to a replacement. See https://github.com/JuliaImages/Images.jl/blob/de7d11fab7937efaa461874f2fa957dc0a31e602/src/deprecations.jl for some examples.

Comment: Thanks @tholy, I edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Julia 1.6, which will go into alpha soon, features a `force` keyword argument that ensures users will see warnings even if they haven't asked for them.