# Making a macro to mark functions as deprecated

Tags: julia, metaprogramming, deprecated

In my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64703350/9988487) I found out that the standard library (Julia v1.5) macro `@deprecate` is used to replace functions by others.

I want to make a macro `mark_deprecated` that has the following effect when applied to a function:

1. Print a customizable deprecation warning when the target function is called (if possible, only for the first time it is called).
2. Modify the function's documentation (viewable as `julia>? function_name`) to also include the deprecation warning.

Of course many other convenient options may be included later, such as the ability to specify a replacement function, an option to produce errors instead of warnings, etc.

**I am mainly doing this as an exercise in Julia metaprogramming**, in which I have zero experience so far (slightly worried this could be too hard as a first task).

### Trying to understand @deprecate

As a first step, I looked at the current Standard Library @deprecate macro. It goes as follows:

```
# julia v1.5
# quoted from deprecated.jl, included by Base.jl

macro deprecate(old, new, ex=true)
    meta = Expr(:meta, :noinline)
    if isa(old, Symbol)
        oldname = Expr(:quote, old)
        newname = Expr(:quote, new)
        Expr(:toplevel,
            ex ? Expr(:export, esc(old)) : nothing,
            :(function $(esc(old))(args...)
                  $meta
                  depwarn($"`$old` is deprecated, use `$new` instead.", Core.Typeof($(esc(old))).name.mt.name)
                  $(esc(new))(args...)
              end))
    elseif isa(old, Expr) && (old.head === :call || old.head === :where)
        remove_linenums!(new)
        oldcall = sprint(show_unquoted, old)
        newcall = sprint(show_unquoted, new)
        # if old.head is a :where, step down one level to the :call to avoid code duplication below
        callexpr = old.head === :call ? old : old.args[1]
        if callexpr.head === :call
            if isa(callexpr.args[1], Symbol)
                oldsym = callexpr.args[1]::Symbol
            elseif isa(callexpr.args[1], Expr) && callexpr.args[1].head === :curly
                oldsym = callexpr.args[1].args[1]::Symbol
            else
                error("invalid usage of @deprecate")
            end
        else
            error("invalid usage of @deprecate")
        end
        Expr(:toplevel,
            ex ? Expr(:export, esc(oldsym)) : nothing,
            :($(esc(old)) = begin
                  $meta
                  depwarn($"`$oldcall` is deprecated, use `$newcall` instead.", Core.Typeof($(esc(oldsym))).name.mt.name)
                  $(esc(new))
              end))
    else
        error("invalid usage of @deprecate")
    end
end
```

My attempts at understanding this thing (NO NEED TO READ IF YOU UNDERSTAND THE MACRO):

- The `:meta` thing is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/meta/#Talking-to-the-compiler-(the-:meta-mechanism)).
- The variables `oldname` and `newname` inside the macro are never used. I assume that this is due to negligence of the developers (as opposed to the declarations having some non-obvious effect despite the variables not being used). I remove them.
- I'm not sure how to handle `a(...) where B` expressions (such an expression enters the toplevel elseif block). Not going to worry about that part for now. It seems like the `where` expression is simply stripped off anyway. Same with `:curly` brackets in the expression. It seems like in any case the function symbol (oldsym) is extracted from the expression (first argument).
- I don't understand what `Base.show_unquoted` does exactly. Seems like it "prints" Expressions into strings just for output so I won't worry about the details.
- The main meat of the macro is of course the returned `Expr`. It asserts that it is evaluated at top level. The export thing I don't care about.
- I have no idea what `Core.Typeof($(esc(oldsym))).name.mt.name` is. It seems to be the actual `Symbol` of the function (as opposed to a string containing the symbol). `Core.Typeof` seems to be the same as `typeof`. You can do `typeof(some_function).name.mt.name` and get the symbol out from the `mt::Core.MethodTable`. Interestingly, the Tab-Completion doesn't seem to work for these low level data-structures and their fields.

### Towards my macro

Trying to plagiarize the above:

```
# julia v1.5
module MarkDeprecated

using Markdown
import Base.show_unquoted, Base.remove_linenums!


"""
    @mark_deprecated old msg 
Mark method `old` as deprecated. 
Print given `msg` on method call and prepend `msg` to the method's documentation.
        MACRO IS UNFINISHED AND NOT WORKING!!!!!
"""
macro mark_deprecated(old, msg="Default deprecation warning.", new=:())
    meta = Expr(:meta, :noinline)
    if isa(old, Symbol)
        # if called with only function symbol, e.g. f, declare method f(args...)
        Expr(:toplevel,
            :(
                @doc(  # This syntax is riddiculous, right?!?
                    "$(Markdown.MD($"`$old` is deprecated, use `$new` instead.", 
                                @doc($(esc(old)))))",
                    function $(esc(old))(args...)
                    $meta
                    warn_deprecated($"`$old` is deprecated, use `$new` instead.", 
                            Core.Typeof($(esc(old))).name.mt.name)
                    $(esc(new))(args...)
                    end
                )
            )
        )
    elseif isa(old, Expr) && (old.head === :call || old.head === :where)
        # if called with a "call", e.g. f(a::Int), or with where, e.g. f(a:A) where A <: Int,
        # try to redeclare that method
        error("not implemented yet.")
        remove_linenums!(new)
        # if old.head is a :where, step down one level to the :call to avoid code duplication below
        callexpr = old.head === :call ? old : old.args[1]
        if callexpr.head === :call
            if isa(callexpr.args[1], Symbol)
                oldsym = callexpr.args[1]::Symbol
            elseif isa(callexpr.args[1], Expr) && callexpr.args[1].head === :curly
                oldsym = callexpr.args[1].args[1]::Symbol
            else
                error("invalid usage of @mark_deprecated")
            end
        else
            error("invalid usage of @mark_deprecated")
        end
        Expr(:toplevel,
            :($(esc(old)) = begin
            $meta
            warn_deprecated($"`$oldcall` is deprecated, use `$newcall` instead.", 
                    Core.Typeof($(esc(oldsym))).name.mt.name)
            $(esc(old)) # TODO: this replaces the deprecated function!!!
        end))
    else
        error("invalid usage of @mark_deprecated")
    end
end


function warn_deprecated(msg, funcsym)
    @warn """
            Warning! Using deprecated symbol $funcsym.
            $msg
            """
end

end # Module MarkDeprecated
```

#### For testing:

```
module Testing

import ..MarkDeprecated  # (if in the same file)

a(x) = "Old behavior"
MarkDeprecated.@mark_deprecated a "Message" print

a("New behavior?")

end
```

### Problems

I so far failed to do any of the two things I wanted:

1. How do I deal with a situation when the caller doesn't import `Markdown`, which I use to concatenate the docstrings? (EDIT: Apparantly this is not a problem? For some reason the modification seems to work despite the module `Markdown` not being imported in the `Testing` module. I don't fully understand why though. It's hard to follow where each part of the macro generated code is executed...)
2. How do I actually avoid replacing the function? Calling it from inside itself creates an infinite loop. I basically need a Python-style decorator? Perhaps the way to do it is to only allow adding the `@mark_deprecated` to the actual function definition? (such a macro would actually be what I was expecting to find in the standard library and just use before I fell down this rabbithole)
3. The macro (which is also true for `@deprecate`) does not affect the method `a(x)` in my example since it only creates a method with signature `a(args...)`, which has lower priority for one argument calls, when the macro is called on the function symbol alone. While not obvious to me, this seems to be desired behaviour for  `@deprecate`. However, is it possible to default application of the macro to the bare function symbol to deprecating *all* methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve is not the same thing as what `Base.@deprecate` does. If I understand correctly:

- you don't want the macro to create a definition for the deprecated method; you want rather to annotate a handwritten definition
- you want to modify docstrings, which `@deprecate` does not

And since you're doing this as an exercise to learn metaprogramming, maybe you could try writing your own macro step by step, rather than understanding how `Base.@deprecate` works and trying to adapt it.

As for your specific questions:

**1. How do I deal with a situation when the caller doesn't import Markdown?**

Maybe the following example helps explaining how things work:

```
module MyModule

# Markdown.MD, Markdown.Paragraph and msg are only available from this module
import Markdown
msg(name) = "Hello $name"

macro greet(name)
    quote
        # function names (e.g. Markdown.MD or msg) are interpolated
        # => evaluated at macro expansion time in the scope of the macro itself
        # => refer to functions available from within the module
        $(Markdown.MD)($(Markdown.Paragraph)($msg($name)))

        # (But these functions are not called at macro expansion time)
    end
end
end
```

See in particular how `msg` correctly refers to `Main.MyModule.msg`, which is how you have to call it from the "outside" context:

```
julia> @macroexpand MyModule.@greet "John"
quote
    #= REPL[8]:8 =#
    (Markdown.MD)((Markdown.Paragraph)((Main.MyModule.msg)("John")))
end

julia> MyModule.@greet "John"
  Hello John
```

**2. Perhaps the way to do it is to only allow adding the @mark_deprecated to the actual function definition?**

Yes, that is what I would do.

**3. Is it possible to default application of the macro to the bare function symbol to deprecating all methods?**

I guess it would technically be possible to deprecate all methods of a given function... or at least all methods that exist at the time when your deprecation code runs. But what about methods that would be defined afterwards?
I personally would not go that way, marking only method definitions.

---

Maybe something like this could be a stub to be used as a starting point for a more complex macro doing precisely what you want:

```
module MarkDeprecate
using Markdown
using MacroTools

function mark_docstring(docstring, message)
    push!(docstring,
          Markdown.Paragraph("Warning: this method is deprecated! $message"))
    docstring
end

function warn_if_necessary(message)
    @warn "This method is deprecated! $message"
end

macro mark_deprecate(msg, expr)
    fundef = splitdef(expr)
    prototype = :($(fundef[:name])($(fundef[:args]...);
                                   $(fundef[:kwargs]...)) where {$(fundef[:whereparams]...)})

    fundef[:body] = quote
        $warn_if_necessary($msg)
        $(fundef[:body])
    end

    quote
        Base.@__doc__ $(esc(MacroTools.combinedef(fundef)))
        Base.@doc $mark_docstring(@doc($prototype), $msg) $prototype
    end
end
end
```

```
julia> """
           bar(x::Number)
       
       some help
       """
       MarkDeprecate.@mark_deprecate "Use foo instead" function bar(x::Number)
           42
       end
bar

julia> """
           bar(s::String)
       
       This one is not deprecated
       """
       bar(s::String) = "not deprecated"
bar

julia> methods(bar)
# 2 methods for generic function "bar":
[1] bar(s::String) in Main at REPL[4]:6
[2] bar(x::Number) in Main at REPL[1]:23

julia> @doc(bar)
  bar(x::Number)

  some help

  Warning: this method is deprecated! Use foo instead

  bar(s::String)

  This one is not deprecated

julia> bar("hello")
"not deprecated"

julia> bar(5)
┌ Warning: This method is deprecated! Use foo instead
└ @ Main.MarkDeprecate REPL[1]:12
42
```